# jquery div closing before hand and is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script the main problem is when I `console.log(schema )`, it shows me `div.tableSpaces` containing all the  `ul` elements  but when I use `.html(schema)`  it closes the `div`

```
function getdatabase(event) {
    var a = $(event).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'getDatabaseSchema',
        data: {
            'adapter': a
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var schema = [];
            $.each(data.table, function(k, v) {
                schema.push("<div class='col-md-5 tableSpaces'>");
                schema.push("<h4>" + k + "</h4>");
                var str = "<ul class=''>";
                $.each(v, function(key, val) {
                    str += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                });
                str += "</ul>";
                schema.push(str);
                schema.push("</div>");
            })
            console.log(schema);
            $("#tablebox").fadeIn();
            $("#tables").html(schema);
        }
    });
}
```

what I'm geting

```
             <div id="tables">
  <!--  See this Div Closes  without any of the h4 or ul  elements within it -->
        <div class="col-md-5 tableSpaces"></div> <-----------------
        <h4>user_department_map</h4>
        <ul class="">
        <li>id</li><li>dep_id</li>
        <li>user_id</li>
        <li>dept_head</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
```

I had a similar problem with the ul then i had to add it to a string

What i require

```
<div id="tables">
  <!--  See here the div incases the h4 an ul elements-->
        <div class="col-md-5 tableSpaces">
        <h4>user_department_map</h4>
        <ul class="">
        <li>id</li><li>dep_id</li>
        <li>user_id</li>
        <li>dept_head</li>
        </ul>
       </div>
        <div>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery, so apart from the answer itself it is easier and makes more sense to use the jQuery objects. `. $('<div class="col-md5 tableSpaces"></div>').append('<h4>' + k + '</h4>')`, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a string before setting it as `.html()`

```
 $("#tables").html(schema.join(''));
```

```js
var schema = [];
schema.push("<div class='col-md-5 tableSpaces'>");
schema.push("<h4>Heading</h4>");
schema.push("<ul class=''>");
schema.push("<li>" + 1 + "</li>");
schema.push("</ul>");
schema.push("</div>");

$("#tables").html(schema.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tables">
  <div>
```

Comment: nice thanks  :D   i completly forgot about this ... i had used it along time back :P